# array not modifying without using static in function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

As array name acts like a pointer to the starting address of the array, so when passed to a function, why the array is not modifying. When I used a static pointer which just storing the address of the array. After that returning the array by using its name is not causing any problem. Why is it so?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a[10]={2,16,19,20,2,9,18};
  int* bubble(int [],int);
  cout<<"the sorted array is ";
  int n=10;
  int *ma=bubble(a,n);
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    cout<<ma[i]<<'\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
int* bubble(int *a,int n)
{
  int no_of_comparisons;
  int ptr,temp;
  static int *ma=a;
  while(no_of_comparisons<=n-1-1)
  {
    ptr=0;
    while(ptr<=n-1-no_of_comparisons-1)
    {
      if(a[ptr]>a[ptr+1])
      {
        temp=a[ptr];
        a[ptr]=a[ptr+1];
        a[ptr+1]=temp;
      }
      ptr+=1;
    }
    no_of_comparisons+=1;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `no_of_comparisons`. A decent compiler should warn you about this. `ma` in `bubble` is unused and that declaration has no effect. If removing `static` changes the behavior, it's because you are already relying on undefined behavior, where any change can have any impact on any part of the behavior.

Comment: Does this even compile with local function `bubble` declared inside main?

Comment: @acraig Sure it does - why not?

Comment: @acraig5075 - a declaration of a function is valid within a function.   A definition (aka implementation) of a function (as distinct from a lambda in C++11 and later, which is something different) is not valid.

Comment: @Peter My mistake, learn something new every day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort is the simplest algorithm to implement and the slowest algorithm on very large inputs, by the way. The basic idea is, just to loop through array from i=0 to n and swap adjacent elements if they are out of order. Below I re-wrote your code, so that it is more readable, clear, and short. I hop it helps.

```
#include<iostream>

int* bubble(int [], int);

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {2, 16, 19, 20, 28, 9, 18, 22, 32,1};
    int arr_size = 10;

    std::cout << "Original Array: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << arr[ i ]<< '\n';

    bubble(arr, arr_size);
    std::cout << "Sorted Array: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << arr[ i ]<< '\n';

    return 0;
}

int* bubble(int *a, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = n - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
            if( a[j] < a[j - 1] )
            {
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

The main problem in your code was, first the no_of_comparisons variable were not initialized. In your case, it should be `0` I think.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: As the code in question has many flaws, an example of how to write code correctly is not that bad.

Comment: @Love Coding thanks for the edit and reply, and the main problem was the no_of_comparisons was not initialized.